# Multiple panels with BoxSizer

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I m trying to divide a single panel into two panels.
So Button1 should be in one panel abd Button 2 , 3, 4 should be on another panel.

Here is my runnable code which does not display the panels correctly.

```
import wx
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class Frame1(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,
                          pos=wx.Point(0, 0),size=wx.Size(800, 200),
                          style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.MAXIMIZE )

        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel2 = wx.Panel(self)
        #self.panel1.SetBackgroundColour('blue')
        self.panel3 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel4 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel3.SetBackgroundColour('red')


        sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer1.Add(self.panel4, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer1.Add(self.panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer1)
        sizer1.Fit(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(sizer1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.panel3, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        #sizer.Fit(self)


        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel3, style=wx.TE_RICH|wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.log, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 15)
        self.panel3.SetSizer(sizer)

        emptycell = (0,0)
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self.panel4, -1, "Button1", size=wx.Size(150, 70))
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self.panel1, -1, "Button2")
        self.button3 = wx.Button(self.panel1, -1, "Button3")
        self.button4 = wx.Button(self.panel1, -1, "Button4")

        sizer = wx.GridSizer(8,3,0,0)

        sizer.Add(emptycell, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.button1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.LEFT, 10)
        sizer.Add(emptycell, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.button2, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        sizer.Add(self.button3, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        sizer.Add(self.button4, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.panel1.SetSizer(sizer)



        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.panel2, -1, self.figure)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.canvas, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel2.SetSizer(sizer)
        #self.panel2.Fit()


        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)

        #self.Center()


#Every wxWidgets application must have a class derived from wxApp
class MyApp(wx.App):
    # wxWidgets calls this method to initialize the application
    def OnInit(self):

        # Create an instance of our customized Frame class
        self.frame = Frame1(None)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = MyApp(0)
    application.MainLoop()
```

Desired result

[image]

Actual result

[image]

Comment: that looks like a "Wrong parent" problem. Make sure you create you buttons with the proper parent and you don't screw up the sizer hierarchy. I'd look into the RAD tool (wxGlade, wxFormBuilder, etc). Install it, run it, make it generate the code and then see what it did generate. This will be a good training excersize. You will understand better how to work with the sizers and will be able to do it by hand in the future more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to hack it about a bit but try to give each panel a sizer of its own and bring them together at the end. Also, use descriptive names, or it soon becomes a morass, which is difficult to follow.

```
import wx
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class Frame1(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,
                          pos=wx.Point(0, 0),size=wx.Size(800, 200),
                          style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.MAXIMIZE )

        self.panel1_1 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel1_2 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel2 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel3 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel3.SetBackgroundColour('red')
        self.panel1_1.SetBackgroundColour('green')
        self.panel1_2.SetBackgroundColour('blue')


        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel3, style=wx.TE_RICH|wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        log_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        log_sizer.Add(self.log, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 15)
        self.panel3.SetSizer(log_sizer)

        self.button1 = wx.Button(self.panel1_1, -1, "Button1", size=wx.Size(150, 70))

        button_sizer1 = wx.GridSizer(1,3,0,0)
        button_sizer1.Add((0,0), 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        button_sizer1.Add(self.button1, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        button_sizer1.Add((0,0), 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.panel1_1.SetSizer(button_sizer1)

        self.button2 = wx.Button(self.panel1_2, -1, "Button2")
        self.button3 = wx.Button(self.panel1_2, -1, "Button3")
        self.button4 = wx.Button(self.panel1_2, -1, "Button4")

        button_sizer2 = wx.GridSizer(1,3,0,0)
        button_sizer2.Add(self.button2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 10)
        button_sizer2.Add(self.button3, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 10)
        button_sizer2.Add(self.button4, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 10)
        self.panel1_2.SetSizer(button_sizer2)

        main_button_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_button_sizer.Add(self.panel1_1)
        main_button_sizer.Add(self.panel1_2, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.panel2, -1, self.figure)

        fig_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        fig_sizer.Add(self.canvas, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel2.SetSizer(fig_sizer)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        main_sizer.Add(main_button_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        main_sizer.Add(self.panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        main_sizer.Add(self.panel3, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        self.Layout()

        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)


#Every wxWidgets application must have a class derived from wxApp
class MyApp(wx.App):
    # wxWidgets calls this method to initialize the application
    def OnInit(self):

        # Create an instance of our customized Frame class
        self.frame = Frame1(None)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = MyApp(0)
    application.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: as written in the questtion, i am trying to separate button 1 and rest of the buttons. So, want only 1 button ( button 1 ) in panel 4 and the rest of the buttons in ( panel 1 ) . Panel 2 is the figure, and panel 3 is the red background panel. the solution you provided is exactly that i have currently running on my system. But this is not what i want.

Comment: Oh dear! I've hacked a fourth panel back in again, although to what point is unclear. Hopefully, it is now close to what you want to achieve. Why the fourth panel?

Comment: The fourth panel is the only active panel when the gui starts. Once the user presses a button in the fourth panel, other panels activate.

Comment: If you color the panels, u will see that panel1_2 does not expand until the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Oof, some of those panel and sizer variable names are hard to follow.

It may be helpful, when dealing with wx, to keep good track of what windows (so, panels, buttons, etc) are going to be inside of what other windows, and be vigilant about how you're declaring the parent of each one.

For instance, if you have one panel (say, `panel1`) that contains multiple elements, then when you instantiate those elements, do so with their parent all set to `panel1`. For instance, when you create `self.button1`, do so with its parent as `panel1` (the same as your other buttons), because you're fitting all of them inside `panel1`.

This is because wx will naturally try to fit windows inside of their parents. When a window has a parent that's one element, but a sizer is trying to put it inside another element, things get pretty screwy. It's hard to follow exactly, but I imagine this is where your problem is.

The other thing that is going to make your code (a) easier to read/follow/debug, and (b) work nicer, is: don't be afraid of instantiating multiple sizer variables. Better yet, give them names that match the panels they're organizing!

I've found it helpful (and this may work for you as well) to divide the `__init__` function into three sections: (1) instantiating all the windows/objects you'll need, from "top level" down, assigning them their correct parent windows; (2) instantiating all your sizers, one for each windows that contains other elements; and (3) from the "bottom level" up, add windows to their parent sizers, calling `SetSizer` on each parent panel, and working up until you set the main sizer for your top-level window.

If that doesn't work out for you, feel free to send me a message and we'll see if we can parse out why wx isn't working out like it should.

Comment: thanks for your tip. better would have been an answer. The code is very simple and an example. Copy and paste in your system and it should run